# Fastest way to find all solutions of the binary equation

Tags: algorithm, math, boolean, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I am trying to find a good solution for the simple problem (relatively simple). Well, I have a human-created binary equation like this one

`A & B & C | D & (E | F) = 1`

So there is a set of binary variables (A, B... up to 12 variables) each can be 0 or 1. And some math operators between them (AND, OR) and also brackets.

I have a large set of (A,B,С...) values (maybe a million or even more) and I need a way to select only those which give 1 on this specific equation.

I definitely don't want to solve this equation for all items from the given list, this will require lots of CPU resources.

Instead, I think there is a way to get a set of value vectors which gives 1 to us and then use this set as a hash table.

May you recommend any method to create such a table of vectors? Any existing algorithm? Thank you.

Sorry, my English, maybe an example will make things clearer:

Let's say we got the equation looks like this: `A & (B | C)` and so the respective list of vectors will be
101, 110, 111.

I need a solution to generate this list for the given equation.

*Why I need that?*

I have developed a fast full-text search algorithm, which works well for phrases too, but now I need to extend it by "OR", "AND" and braces meta-operators to add some flexibility as Google does.

For example, if the user entered the query "master and margarita" it will find the word "master" (A) and the word "margarita" (B) in all documents. Thus we have a set of A, B for each document. Next, we have the equation `A & B` and all we need is just find documents that give 1 for this equation. When the user entered "master OR margarita", the equation will be "A OR B", etc.

Comment: Can we know why you want that ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have added an explanation to the initial post, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Sure 12 variables is more than enough. Then I guess that an array of 2^n booleans is a good solution (n is the number of variables).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the wonderful world of the "N = NP" conjecture.

No one knowns for sure if it is possible to solve such problems faster than by exhaustive trial, which takes `2^N` evaluations for an expression of `N` variables.

Anyway, for `N` as small as `12`, there are just `4096` combinations, not millions, and brute force is probably the best option.

To represent the solutions, you have at least two options:

- hold a single bit 0/1 per combination. You will need `512` bytes.
- store every solution explicitly using `12` bits words. In this case, the total number of bits required isn't known in advance. It can be as low as 0 but as "high" as 3072 bytes :-(

---

Using brute force, I guess that you can handle up to 30 variables or so.

Comment: There is no `not` operator listed.  Without that, this is not NP-complete.

Comment: @btilly Yes, NOT is also possible there, I think. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you need to solve this problem is a parser for the expressions and you could recursively determine which solutions for A, B, ... are necessary to make the equation true. In fact, Logical Programming languages (like Prolog etc.) do exactly that. And it would list you all possible solution for A, B, ... in the equation which would finally give True.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you have a data set which includes all of the combinations of true/false and maybe some other data.  You want to pull out just the members of the data set that make the equation true without having to evaluate it for every one.

Since there are only 4096 combinations, you should be able to create a lookup table from combination of truth values to the rows in the data set that have that combination.

Then when you get an equation you can try it out on each combination of booleans, then just do a lookup on the keys that returned true.  (You can actually be smarter about generating the list of combinations of booleans that will satisfy the equation, but you still need the data stored by combination of booleans to generate the list of answers without evaluating each one.) You don't look at the other rows.